# Pandas: Produce column percentages relative to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks as follows

| Stu | Athlete | Baseball | Cheer | Football |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I would like to calculate the percentage of total athletes as well as the percentage of each athlete group within the athlete population (in other words athlete/count and sport/athlete).

I'd like to get an output like the following:

| header 1 |  |
| --- | --- |
| Athlete | 75 |
| Baseball | 33 |
| Cheer | 33 |
| Football | 33 |

I'm able to achieve this by running individual statements such as:

```python
df['Athlete'].sum()/df['Count'].sum() * 100

df['Baseball'].sum()/df['Athlete'].sum() * 100
```

etc...

But is there a way to issue a statement that performs this without individual statement creation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and assigning a new df

```py
sport_pct = (df.iloc[:, 2:].sum() / df['Athlete'].sum() * 100).astype(int)
athlete_pct = int(df['Athlete'].sum() / len(df) * 100)

new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'header 1': ['Athlete'] + list(sport_pct.index),
    '': [athlete_pct] + list(sport_pct.values)
})
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   header 1    
0   Athlete  75
1  Baseball  33
2     Cheer  33
3  Football  33
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# calculate total number of athletes
total_athletes = df['Athlete'].sum()

# calculate percentage of athletes for each sport
sport_percentages = df[['Baseball', 'Cheer', 
'Football']].sum().apply(lambda x: x/total_athletes * 100)

# calculate percentage of athletes in each group
group_percentages = df[['Baseball', 'Cheer', 'Football']].apply(lambda x: 
x/df['Athlete'].sum() * 100)

# concatenate the two results into one DataFrame
result = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Athlete': [total_athletes]}), 
sport_percentages.to_frame().transpose(), group_percentages])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try groupby and agg, like this:

```
# group by 'Athlete' 
result = df.groupby('Athlete').agg(
    Total=('Athlete', 'size'),
    Baseball_Percentage=('Baseball', 'mean'),
    Cheer_Percentage=('Cheer', 'mean'),
    Football_Percentage=('Football', 'mean')
)

# calculate the percentage
result['Percentage_of_Total_Athletes'] = result['Total'] / result['Total'].sum() * 100
```